# Android scrollview buttons effect

Tags: android, scroll, imageview, scrollview

Is there any kind of soulution for this problem?
I need ImageView have effect of clicking on it (the code below).
But it becomes "half-clicked" when i leaf it in my ScrollView.

```
public class ViewHighlighterOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {     

          final ImageView imageButton;
          public ViewHighlighterOnTouchListener(final ImageView imageButton) {
            super();
            this.imageButton = imageButton;
          }
          public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              //grey color filter, you can change the color as you like
              imageButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(155, 185, 185, 185));
            } else if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
             imageButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(0, 185, 185, 185)); 
            }
            return false;
          }
        }
```

Comment: I think you need hover effect on that button indicating that the button is clicked. You can do this using xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
Create a xml file in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/enquiry_hover" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/enquiry_normal"/>
</selector>
```

here declare colors with names enquiry_hover,enquiry_normal in color.xml file in values folder .